# Открыть файл при помощи Java-программы, и получить Path этого файла

Tags: java, файлы

**Что бы вопрос был понятнее, приведу аналогию:**

Когда тыкаешь по txt файлу открывается блокнот с содержимым файла, если конечно не другое приложение стоит, а я как раз вместо блокнота хочу подставить свою скомпилированную* программу

**Лучше конечно с jar, но можно и с exe*

---

**Цель такова:**

**Сделать так, что бы при нажатии по файлу с определенным расширением (например txt), открывался JFrame с текстом из этого файла (по которому кликнули)**

Создавать JFrame и читать файли по Path, я умею, но как узнать path этого файла?

---

**Если вообще нет вариантов, то можно вот есть с bat файлом (Спасибо [Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina)):**

Создаём где-нибудь файл, называем его `myfile.myext`.
Создаём где-нибудь bat-файл, называем его `mybatch.bat`.
Редактируем bat-файл, пишем в него:

```
start javaw -jar Java_Program.jar %1
```

ПКМ по файлу >> Открыть с помощью >> Другие приложения >> bat-файл с программой

Path будет поступать в `String[]` у метода `main`
Пример кода для проверки:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String string : args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "End");
}
```

Comment: Используйте системное "Открыть с помощью" и поставьте галку "Всегда использовать эту программу". Первым параметром программе передаётся полное имя файла, с путём и прочими причиндалами. Если надо - в реестре можно подрихтовать строку запуска. PS. Настоятельно не рекомендую изменять существующие ассоциации - лучше изобретите собственное расширение.

Comment: Это-то я умею, но цель-то получить Path файла, который открыли при помощи моей программы

Comment: Я ж вроде сказал, что программе будет передано полное имя файла, с диском и путём. Вот и вытащи его из параметров.

Comment: Из main? Но мне туда ничего не поступает

Comment: Вы сказали, что "это-то Вы умеете". Если Вы смогли ассоциировать кастомное расширение со своей программой - то открываемый по этой ассоциации файл передаётся полным путём как первый параметр.

Comment: Я так и делал, но длинна массива **String[] arg** у меня равна 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По шагам.

1. Создаём где-нибудь файл, называем его `myfile.myext`.
2. Создаём где-нибудь батч-файл, называем его `mybatch.bat`.
3. Редактируем батч-файл, пишем в него:

```sh
@echo Batch-file name: %0
@echo Filename: %1
pause
```

4. Кликаем правым батоном по файлу, Открыть с помощью - Другие приложения - тычем в батч-файл. Открывается окно CMD, убеждаемся, что в нём отображается полное имя батч-файла и полное имя нашего файла. Закрываем окно.
5. Двойной клик по файлу, открывается окно CMD, убеждаемся, что в нём отображается полное имя батч-файла и полное имя нашего файла. Закрываем окно.
6. Идём разбираться с передачей параметров в Java-приложение.

Для справки - в реестре создаются два раздела: `HKCR\.myext` и `HKCR\myext_auto_file`. Можете их изучить... и потом удалить - за явной ненадобностью.

Comment: С⁣п⁣а⁣с⁣и⁣б⁣о⁣!⁣